# Parsing Dictionary Into Spreadsheet in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have some data in this similar format:

```
James has 6 jeans, 10 shirts, 5 shoes, 6 ties
Nick has 8 jeans, 4 shirts, 3 shoes, 4 ties
Adam has 2 jeans, 3 shirts, 5 shoes, 1 tie
John has 6 jeans, 5 shirts, 10 shoes, 3 ties
```

Using `collections.defaultdict(list)`, I produced a dictionary in the follow format:

```
{James: [[Jeans, 6],
         [Shirts, 10],
         [Shoes, 5],
         [Ties, 6]],
 Nick: [[Jeans, 8],
        [Shirts, 4],
        [Shoes, 3],
        [Ties, 4]],
 Adam: [[Jeans, 2],
        [Shirts, 3],
        [Shoes, 5],
        [Ties, 1]],
 John: [[Jeans, 6],
        [Shirts, 5],
        [Shoes, 10],
        [Ties, 3]]}
```

I am trying to get this output in a cvs spreadsheet:

```
Accesories  James    Nick       Adam     John

Jeans         6       8           2        6

Shirts       10       4           3        5

Shoes        5        3           5        10

Ties         6        4           1         3
```

After doing some coding prior to build the dictionary, here is the code I have so far to try to produce a spreadsheet identical to format, above, using the dictionary that was created. `cvs` ,`itertools` modules are already imported.

```
with open(outputcsv, 'w') as w:
    writer = csv.writer(w, delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(dict.keys())

    zipped = itertools.izip_longest(*dict.values())
    writer.writerows(list(zipped))
```

This gets me fairly close to the intended solution but not quite.

Comment: can you modify your datastructure a bit...instead of having key'd on names , can you have it key'd on accessories?..example: {"Jeans" : [1,2,3,4], "Shirts": [...], this way when you write to the file, you can simply do... f.write(x + ",".join(str(a) for a in d[x]) while iterating over d...the header is fairly easy to add, as "Accessories" + ",".join(names) where names is a list of people in question (such as james, nick etc)

Comment: im not sure what the x and a is in your snippet as it pertains to my code? The names, accesories, and the number are all related, the dictionary needs to be accessing all members so I am not sure your suggestion would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easier as a dict of dicts rather than a dict of list of lists.

Assume:

```
w={'James': {'Jeans': 6,
     'Shirts': 10,
     'Shoes': 5,
     'Ties': 6,},
 'Nick': {'Jeans': 8,
    'Shirts': 4,
    'Shoes': 3,
    'Ties': 4},
 'Adam': {'Jeans': 2,
    'Shirts': 3,
    'Shoes': 5,
    'Ties': 1},
 'John': {'Jeans': 6,
    'Shirts': 5,
    'Shoes': 10,
    'Ties': 3,
    'Belts': 1}}
```

Notice `John` has a belt and the others do not and this is a dict of dicts rather than a dict of lists of two elements lists.

First, let's get a list (ok, a set...) of all the accessories that anyone has:

```
accessories=set()    
for nam, di in w.items():
    for k in di:
        accessories.add(k)  
>>> accessories
set(['Ties', 'Belts', 'Jeans', 'Shirts', 'Shoes'])
```

Now it is straightforward to create a CSV of these items in your format:

```
import csv

with open('/tmp/so.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['accessories']+w.keys()) 
    for item in accessories:
        li=[item]
        for nam in w:
            li.append(w[nam].get(item, 0))
        writer.writerow(li)
```

Now look at the file:

```
accessories,James,John,Adam,Nick
Ties,6,3,1,4
Belts,0,1,0,0
Jeans,6,6,2,8
Shirts,10,5,3,4
Shoes,5,10,5,3
```

If you are stuck with a dict of a list of lists each two elements (as you have in your example) you can convert them:

```
>>> w={'James': [['Jeans', 6],
...      ['Shirts', 10],
...      ['Shoes', 5],
...      ['Ties', 6]],
...  'Nick': [['Jeans', 8],
...     ['Shirts', 4],
...     ['Shoes', 3],
...     ['Ties', 4]],
...  'Adam': [['Jeans', 2],
...     ['Shirts', 3],
...     ['Shoes', 5],
...     ['Ties', 1]],
...  'John': [['Jeans', 6],
...     ['Shirts', 5],
...     ['Shoes', 10],
...     ['Ties', 3],
...     ['Belts', 1]]}
>>> {k:dict(LoL) for k, LoL in w.items()}
{'James': {'Ties': 6, 'Jeans': 6, 'Shirts': 10, 'Shoes': 5}, 'John': {'Ties': 3, 'Belts': 1, 'Jeans': 6, 'Shirts': 5, 'Shoes': 10}, 'Adam': {'Ties': 1, 'Jeans': 2, 'Shirts': 3, 'Shoes': 5}, 'Nick': {'Ties': 4, 'Jeans': 8, 'Shirts': 4, 'Shoes': 3}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll have to look at it more closely but I'm not sure where you are getting the idea about belts? No one has belts...or was that something you added?

Comment: It is fairly fragile to assume that list of accessories is fixed, isn't it?

Comment: They aren't...that's what makes this more challenging. None of the 3 variables are fixed. This is just a snapshot of about 500 more rows and 20 more columns that's why I'm trying to make the code versatile.